# ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xff

Tags: postgresql

Im importing a databse called adventure works to postgresql

and these message appears

ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xff
CONTEXT:  COPY businessentity, line 1
SQL state: 22021

Comment: What are you *actually* doing? `COPY` doesn't import databases (there's no such thing), it imports text or data files, not database backup files. AdventureWorks is a SQL Server sample database. Did you try to import the SQL Server database backup file as if it was a CSV ?

Comment: I found a script for the database, in the script it copy the csv files

CREATE TABLE BusinessEntity
(BusinessEntityID SERIAL,     
rowguid uuid NOT NULL CONSTRAINT "DF_BusinessEntity_rowguid" DEFAULT uuid_generate_v1(),ModifiedDate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL CONSTRAINT "DF_BusinessEntity_ModifiedDate" DEFAULT (NOW()))

SELECT 'Copying data into Person.BusinessEntity';
copy Person.BusinessEntity FROM 'C:\Users\Ernesto Cabrera\Desktop\Practical SQL\Adventure\BusinessEntity.csv' DELIMITER E'\t' CSV;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says, the byte 0xFF isn't valid in a UTF8 file. Since you're trying to load data from a SQL Server sample database I suspect the file was saved as UTF16 with [a Byte Order Mark](https://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#bom1). Unicode isn't a single encoding. Unicode text files can contain a signature at the start which specifies the encoding used in the file. As the link shows, for UTF16 the BOM can be `0xFF 0xFE` or `0xFE 0xFF`, values which are invalid in UTF8.

As far as I know you can't specify a UTF16 encoding with COPY, so you'll have to either convert the CSV file to UTF8 with a command line tool or export it again as UTF8. If you exported the data using any SQL Server tool (SSMS, SSIS, bcp) you can easily specify the encoding you want. For example :

```
bcp Person.BusinessEntity out "c:\MyPath\BusinessEntity.csv" -c -C 65001
```

Will export the data using the 65001 codepage, which is UTF8

Comment: im beyond my knowledge here, but thanks for your response! i just wanted to open the sample database to keep practicing but i wasnt unable to make it work

Comment: Where did you find that CSV file? A CSV file isn't a database, it's a plain old text file with data stored as values separated by commas, eg `1,John Doe,US`. CSV stands for Comma Separated Values. You can use tools like `iconv` to convert the file from UTF16 to UTF8 and load it