# Why does Cloud SQL Import work only when special characters are near the top of the CSV file?

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql

Using the Cloud SQL import function, I get this error when attempting to upload my CSV.

```
generic::failed_precondition: ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xc2 0xc2 CONTEXT: COPY <TABLE_NAME>, line 37468
```

When you move this 37468 row up to the top row, the file successfully uploads. It appears that the underlying API or the database does some type of parsing. How can I get the upload to work regardless of where these special characters are?

Comment: In the process of editing the file to rearrange the lines, maybe your editor fixed the encoding issue.  Or if the import is expecting an (ignored) header row, then putting the broken line at the top would mean it is ignored.

Comment: I just tried, bad encoding still trigger errors even when in an ignored header.

Comment: Good idea, but it will work if the line is on the second row, for example.

Comment: The bad text in question looks like this: 1&val=ì�¨ì�´ì �ì�¤

Comment: You have to figure out the actual encoding of the data and tell `COPY` about it.

Comment: As mentioned by jjanes and Laurenz Albe, this is an issue with your encoding. I found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70701839/error-invalid-byte-sequence-for-encoding-utf8-0xff) that can help you.